# Method size() cannot be found on java.lang.String type

Tags: spring-integration

```
<int:router input-channel="fromCloud_List_profile" expression="payload.size() > 0">
        <int:mapping value="true" channel="map_profile_response"/>
</int:router>
```

Trying to get the size of the response payload from outbound which is a JSON array. but I am gettin the following error.

```
Expression evaluation failed: payload.size() > 0; nested exception is
 org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos
 8): Method call: Method size() cannot be found on java.lang.String type
```

Any idea what is the issue here?

Comment: looks like payload is a string rather than an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the payload is coming in a json string format. I resolved the issues by using #jsonpath.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html#spel-functions